# Is there a 'this' function in SASS?

Tags: sass

I am building a grid mixin in SASS (scss to be precise) and just wondering if there is something like @this available.  The @this would refer to the element which is being styled.

Like this:

```
@mixin grid(args n stuff) {
    float: left;
    & + @this {
        float; right;
    }
}

div.grid {
    @include grid;
}
```

which would produce:

```
div.grid {
    float: left;
}

div.grid + div.grid {
    float: right;
}
```

Would be ruddy awesome if this is possible.

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the `&`:

```
@mixin grid() {
    float: left;
    & + & {
        float: right;
    }
}

div.grid {
    @include grid;
}
```

Output:

```
div.grid {
  float: left;
}

div.grid + div.grid {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: [parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)